# ofstream doesn't work on Windows 7 hidden file

Tags: c++, windows-7

I realize that `ofstream` doesn't work on Windows 7 hidden file.

Here is the quick test code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {    
    {
        std::ifstream file2(_T("c:\\a.txt"));
        if (file2.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "ifstream open" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "ifstream not open!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // SetFileAttributes(_T("c:\\a.txt"), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
    SetFileAttributes(_T("c:\\a.txt"), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);

    {
        std::ofstream file(_T("c:\\a.txt"));
        if (file.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "ofstream open" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "ofstream not open!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
ifstream open
ofstream not open!
```

If I am using `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`, `ofstream` will be opened successfully.

I do not run the program as Administrator. But, I do use the following linker option.

[image: linker options]

Having to turn **No** for **Enable User Account Control (UAC)** is important, if we do not start the application as Administrator. OS will help us to write the actual file to `C:\Users\yccheok\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\a.txt` instead of protected `C:\`

Does `ofstream` fail on Windows 7 hidden file, is an expected behaviour?

Comment: Which of those seven linker options is the one you're referring to when you say you use "the following linker option," and why do you think it's important to mention? Is the virtual store actually relevant to this question?

Comment: I update the information, to help you to understand why turning No for UAC is important.

Comment: Have you tried closing the `ifstream` before opening the `ofstream`?

Comment: I had tried to close `ifstream` explicitly before opening `ofstream`. It still behave the same.

Comment: Write your file somewhere other than the root of C. UAC treats the root of C specially. See if the behaviour persists in a more ordinary path.

Comment: Please add Information which Compiler you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As noted in the underlying [`CreateFile` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx), " If `CREATE_ALWAYS` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` are specified, `CreateFile` fails and sets the last error to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if the file exists and has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` attribute."

Or more readable: `CreateFile` fails if both `CREATE_ALWAYS` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` are specified, and if the file has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` and/or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` attribute.

It just so happens that `ofstream` calls `CreateFile` like this.

Comment: But wierd, the documentation as you citied above are specified for "Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000". But I only encounter this problem in Windows 7. I didn't encounter such problem in Windows XP.

Comment: I thought the problem is in Windows 7 only. I do further testing. It seems like it is in Windows XP too.