# How open a hidden file in c++ programming?

Tags: c++, file, c++builder

I'm programming with c++ Builder . I want to open a hidden text file. I make the text file hidden intentionly for security reasons.

In normal way we use fopen() to open a file but if file is hidden, this function fail and return false statement.

Is there any way to check for existanse of a hidden file?
(I Only need to check it's existance at first step)

Comment: Hidden files are a property of the OS/Filesystem. C++ doesn't have a notion of that.

Comment: This statement - `if file is hidden, this function fail` is not true. You can `fopen` hidden files the same ways non-hidden files are opened.

Comment: If you need security, then I would recommend encrypting it. Marking it as hidden won't stop anybody.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Security through obscurity does not work well

Comment: This SO question may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530397/ofstream-doesnt-work-on-windows-7-hidden-file

Comment: Actually Problem is with conflict by Antivirus SW and my system hidden file. According to @πάνταῥεῖ C++ has no problem with hidden files. My error origin was Privileges.

Comment: Testing with a short program shows that `fopen(, "rb")` succeeds and `fopen(, "wb")` fails. That complies to the question linked in Galik's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the **GetFileAttributes** function. It will work for this.
Reference link : [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx).